# thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to go from the `main.java` (a splash screen) to `Intro.java` in my Android application. But I am getting the following error...

```
thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
```

This is my code...

main.java:

```
public class main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

boolean _active = true;
final int _splashTime = 2000; // time to display the splash screen in ms

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);



    // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
    Thread splashTread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                    sleep(100);

                    // waited is incremented by 100 after every sleep for 100 ms
                    if(_active) {
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch(InterruptedException e) {

            }
            finally {

                    finish();

                    Intent inte = new Intent(main.this, Intro.class);
                    startActivity(inte);
                    }
        }
    };

    splashTread.start();


}
// this is to skip splash screen by touch event
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        _active = false;
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

Intro.java

```
public abstract class Intro extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    Log.d("Error"," Intro Started ");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.intro);


     RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.intro);
     layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)
    {
         Log.d("Error"," Touch Listener set "); 

        Intent i=new Intent(Intro.this,features.class);  
        startActivity(i);
        return false;
    }


});
}
}
```

The intro.java was supposed to go to features.java by touch of user...

manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ubuntu.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ubundroid"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity   android:name=".Intro" />
    <activity   android:name=".Feature"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

The Logcat :

```
 D/dalvikvm(1229): newInstance failed: p0 i0 [0 a1
 D/AndroidRuntime(1229): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(1229): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1229): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(1229): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ubuntu.app/        com.ubuntu.app.Intro}: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.ubuntu.app.Intro
 E/AndroidRuntime(1229):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1229):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1229):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1229):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1229):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1229): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.ubuntu.app.Intro
E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1229):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1229):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1229):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1229):    ... 11 more
```

Thanks in advance...

=========================== EDITED =====================================

It started running when i deleted all the touch events in the Intro.java.
the new java file was :

```
package com.ubuntu.app;

import android.app.Activity;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;



public  class Intro extends Activity
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    Log.d("Error"," Intro Started ");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.intro);

}
}
```

But I would like to get the right way to go to next activity by touch of user..

Comment: see my comments in my answer, it is so basic ....how can you miss this

Comment: I have write code for you check .........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ubuntu.app/
  com.ubuntu.app.Intro}: java.lang.InstantiationException:
  com.ubuntu.app.Intro

..

```
public abstract class Intro extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

intro is an abstract class can't make it instance so when you launch this class android will try to create it's instance that will give error

I think I have to write the code

```
public  class Intro extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    Log.d("Error"," Intro Started ");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.intro);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    //handle button event 
} 
}
```

Comment: When i delete the abstract ,

there is an error " type intro must implement the inherited abstarct method " and they ask me to make it abstract..

Comment: @ Agu as you are implements OnClickListener listener it's so simple ...override onClick function ... and remove the abstract keyword

Comment: @11684 are you sure? have you read Exception ? InstantiationException

Comment: read from here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/InstantiationException.html

Comment: Thrown when an application tries to create an instance of a class using the newInstance method in class Class, but the specified class object cannot be instantiated because it is an interface or is an abstract class.

Comment: @Agu Please override in your activity onClick(View v) {} and remove abstract keyword ...

Comment: I did it... It requires abstarct keyword as long as there is  " implements onClickListener "

When I deleted both onClick and abstarct and tried to run it, it gave the old error...

Comment: RESOLVED ! Thanks Dhareesh Singh

That touch codes were problem... Click listeners works good.

Comment: @DheereshSingh Yes, you're right! Sorry, I'm accustomed to the normal VM. There it looks slightly differently I believe.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
Intent i=new Intent(Intro.this,Feature.class);  
        startActivity(i);
```

instead of

```
 Intent i=new Intent(Intro.this,features.class);  
        startActivity(i);
```

or if features is your Activity then Register it also as in manifest:

```
<activity   android:name=".features"/>
```

Comment: you have try after removing abstract from Intro Activity?

Comment: remove abstract from Intro Activity and  import  **import android.view.View.OnClickListener;** in Intro Activity

Comment: if I remove abstract , i get error and can't run..

Or they ask me to make include dialogueinterface override and all..

Comment: It says import android.view.View.OnClickListener; collides with another import statement..

Comment: use **Activity implements View.OnClickListener** instead of **Activity implements OnClickListener**

Comment: No. I would like to go to next activity by Touch of user.

Comment: Not Resolved.. I was just providing the information that there is some problem with the code what I have written for Touch..